# package com.google.android.gms.samples.wallet.databinding does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-pay

I'am following a tutorial from here https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart , i downloaded the code and try to run it but it complains about

```
 package com.google.android.gms.samples.wallet.databinding does not exist
```

which is logically true , as the package does not exist , but i assume downloading from the official site i should not be facing such problem.

I have not changed anything from the link i just downloaded and ran it in my Android studio. how do i resolve this??
Please help.

**Versions**

Android Studio version : 4.01 
Android Version : 7.1.2 
google-play : 2020.10.22037

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Google for the same issue, and was told

> The class is generated from View binding. View binding is enabled from build.gradle (you can find it from github as well)

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = 
    true
}
```

And given [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#data-binding) to the relevant documentation.